# Error 404 after deploying webservice war in glassfish4

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I am new to web services, i have copied the war in the auto deploy folder of glassfish and it is deployed but when i hit the url

[image]

i get error 404. 
The context root is

```
com.abc.def.ghi
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the glassfish 4 installer did not have a web service engine in it.

Comment: It doesn't have WHAT in it?

Comment: in the administration console, when i click on applications i could see engines, it should have webservices,web